# URL Rewrite Custom Header into a Cookie

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a client making http requests to a WebAPI. The API's are secured using a cookie; however, this client is unable to send cookies. This client is able to send custom http headers. So can we use the rewrite module to take a custom http header and set it as the cookie.

I have added HTTP_COOKIE as a server variable. Where I am strugling is the condition. How do I set the condition to pull a custom http header, and set it as a cookie.

**EDIT**
So I got the header being copied to the cookie using the rule below

```
            <rule name="cookie" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                <match url=".+" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_COOKIE" value="{C:0}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="None" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ccauth}" pattern=".+" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```

Now it overwrites the cookie, so I need to append to it instead...

Comment: Cookies are headers. How can a client send headers but not cookies?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I know doesn't make sense but in iOS using WkWebView we've had issues setting cookies. When we set the HTTP header on an XHR request it complains we are setting an insecure header. When our site issues a set-cookie header the client no longer honors it. With UIView now being deprecated in iOS 14 we are looking for a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires two rules, one to set the cookie if there is no cookie and another to append it to the cookies if there is a cookie

```
<rule name="Append Auth Header to Cookies" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".+"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_ccauth}" pattern="(.+)"/>
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="(.+)"/>
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_COOKIE" value="{C:1}{C:2}"/>
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Set Auth Header to Cookies" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".+"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_ccauth}" pattern="(.+)"/>
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_COOKIE" value="{C:1}"/>
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None"/>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if the WebAPI is secured by using a cookie, the client should be authenticated by the WebAPI authentication(JWT,Asp.Net identity) system instead of setting a local cache to transfer the credentials.  if the client cookies could be set up by `JS/Postman`, the system is not secure, HttpOnly kind of cookies is advisory.
Besides, you could add a query string in the URL to determine if setting up a local cache. Please refer to the below links.
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/2xb6a5/is_there_a_way_to_add_a_setcookie_header_using/
https://clarify.dovetailsoftware.com/gsherman/2011/01/20/using-the-url-rewrite-module-to-set-your-cookies-to-httponly/

Comment: Yes if I could I use HttpOnly cookie. Problem is iOS in hybrid mobile apps cookies no longer work in their WebKitView which from what I gather from our mobile team is required to be use in iOS 14. So if the XHR client won't honor the set-cookie header, and we can't even set our own cookies on an individual request, then we are forced into doing something else